# Edit element in arraylist, find index?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm about to create two methods for creating and changing customer profiles. Creating profile is no problem. Everything seems to go well there. But, when I shall then go in and change the profile, I get it not to work.

The indexOf() gives me -1, even though the value I search for available :S

Anyone have a good solution to this?

***The problem is in the editProfile-method!***

```
public class Profile{
    String name;
    long id;
    int accNr = 1000;
    double balance;
}

ArrayList<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();

public boolean newProfile(long id, String name, int amount){
    Profile newProfile = new Profile();
    Profile accNr = new Profile();

    int ACC = accNr.accNr++;

    newProfile.accNr = ACC;
    newProfile.id = id;
    newProfile.name = name;
    newProfile.balance = amount;

    profileList.add(newProfile);

    return true;
}

public void editProfile(long id, String newName){
    int ID = (int)id;
    System.out.print(ID);
    int index = profileList.indexOf(id);
    System.out.print(index);

    profileList.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf` method will use the `equals` method to determine if your `Profile` exists in the list.  You must override the [`equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in `Profile` to return the proper result.

Second, it won't find your `Profile`, because you are passing a `long` to `indexOf`, and neither a `long` nor a `Long` will be found in the list.  If you must retrieve the `Profile` by a `long`, then it makes more sense to have a `Map<Long, Profile>` instead of an `ArrayList<Profile>`.  Then you can call `get(id)` to retrieve the `Profile`.  Usually, you should override the [`hashCode` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) if you override `equals`, but because a `Profile` isn't being used as the key here, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`profileList` contains `Profile` instances and you are trying to get the index of a `long`.

One solution would be overriding `equals` method in `Profile` class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    ...
}
```

Another solution (not very recommended) would be looping over elements of `profileList` and manually checking for matches, like:

```
for (Profile element : profileList)
    if (element.getID() == id)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `Profile`needs to override equals and hashCode methods. Eclipse can generate then, Would be like taking your example:

```
public class Profile {
String name;
long id;
int accNr = 1000;
double balance; 
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + accNr;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(balance);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Profile other = (Profile) obj;
    if (accNr != other.accNr)
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(balance) != Double
            .doubleToLongBits(other.balance))
        return false;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}